# PHP automatic redirect after log in instead of CLICK HERE

Tags: php, mysql

### how can i redirect automatically after log in, instead of click "CLICK HERE"

how can i redirect automatically after log in, instead of click "CLICK HERE"

```
   if (isset($_POST['user']))
   {
      $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
      $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);

      if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
      {
         $error = "Not all fields were entered <br />";
      }
      else
      {
          $query = "SELECT user,pass FROM vbmembers
                Where user='$user' AND pass='$pass'";

          if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0)
          {
              $error = "Username/Password invalid<br />";
          }
          else
          {
              $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
              $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
              die ("You are logged in. Please
                <a href='vbmembers.php?view=$user'>Click here</a>.");
          }
      }
   }  
}
```

Comment: What's the question?? It's pure code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP `header`

```
header('Location: http://example.com/vbmembers.php?view=' . $user);
```

Replace this

```
die ("You are logged in. Please
            <a href='vbmembers.php?view=$user'>Click here</a>.");
```

Comment: Already saw it. but i dont know where i have to use it exactly?

Comment: Edited my post. Please check.

Comment: @Vano, it will redirect automatically. That's how `header` works. Remove the `die` function and add `header` code snippet from my post.

Comment: thank you very much Samir. Worked fine.